# Executing a Drive fileList.execute() causes ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I've been trying to incorporate reading data from Google Drive to my Android application.  I started by following the instructions for the sample application (DriveQuickstart - https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android ) and encountered the same error.  The issue is that when I call fileList.execute(); in the following code the debugger complains that the BaseDexClassLoader has thrown a ClassNotFoundException.  If I catch this exception and print the message, it tells me that the parameter string should not be null.  I ensured that I had followed all the directions for setting up the project, as I'm sure this is something wrong with my environment.  I've played around with the Java Build Path, and the Android target for this project (currently set to Android + Google API) but nothing helps.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
    private void downloadFile() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
            Files.List fileList = service.files().list().setQ("title = 'tester'");
            FileList files = fileList.execute();  //This line causes an exception when executed.
              ArrayList<File> myFiles = new ArrayList<File>(1);
              myFiles.addAll(files.getItems());
              File file = myFiles.get(0);
              InputStream inStream = downloadFile(service,file);
              String docText = convertStreamToString(inStream);
              Log.v("TAG", docText);
          }
          catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
          startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString() );
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }
```

And here is the method from the sample app that encounters the same issue:

```
  private void saveFileToDrive() {
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      // File's binary content
      java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
      FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

      // File's metadata.
      File body = new File();
      body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
      body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

      File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute(); //Same exception encountered
      if (file != null) {
        showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
        startCameraIntent();
      }
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
      startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
t.start();
```

}

Comment: Have you tried following the video tutorial? The ClassNotFoundException is being thrown because some jars are missing

Comment: Yes I watched the video tutorial and I've recreated the project multiple times only to have the same error occur, even with the sample project.  I think it was working on a Windows7 machine, but I can't avoid this exception on this XP machine.

Comment: If you are working with the emulator, I'd also recommend you to try again with a real device

Comment: I'm working with a real device, Droid RAZR with Android 4.0.4.  I thought maybe it was my phone, but the Drive app works fine on it.  Somehow the drive QuickStart app worked once! But trying to reproduce the working results has been unfruitful, still class not found exception after the .execute().

Comment: I've now tried to create the example project on two different machines and am encountering the same problem, I've followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) each time.

Comment: Update:  I've found that the Drive Quickstart app works if the error I have suspending the thread is just swallowed.  I noticed that the app was working when just being run and not debugged.  I added an additional "catch" after the line that was causing trouble and now I can debug the code and it works fine.  It seems odd to me though that this exception seems to occur and just must be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Using Birdman's own solution I got the part where I added an extra catch(Exception e) to work too. Even though It may only be a semi-solution.

> Update: I've found that the Drive Quickstart app works if the error I have suspending the thread is just swallowed. I noticed that the app was working when just being run and not debugged. I added an additional "catch" after the line that was causing trouble and now I can debug the code and it works fine. It seems odd to me though that this exception seems to occur and just must be ignored. – birdman Jan 23 at 20:06

Answer (score 0):

Select Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries from the Eclipse menu.

Have you tried check the Android privated Libraries on [order and export] of [java build path].

Or update to the lastest the android sdk and google api version?